# Memory error when applying a lambda function to create a new column in a panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, apply

I am trying to create a new column in a pandas dataframe based on a user defined function by using df.apply with a lambda. The dataframe is 241573 rows and I am getting a memory error before the statement completes.

Example of current code:

```
def func(col1,col2,col3)
    if "string1" in col2
        return col3
    else "string2" in col2
        return col1

df.apply(lambda x: func(x["column1"],x["column2"],x["column3"]), axis = 1)
```

In the example above I have simplified the function so for any solutions that do not utilise the format above the actual function also includes another elif which takes a column that contains lists in each cell and iterates through the list performing some string functions to remove certain substrings. That is why I originally chose to use a lambda as it was easiest to write as a function.

The error just states not enough memory to create array.

All solutions and suggestions welcome.

Comment: Where are you using `x` in the lambda? at the moment you take the whole columns (3 times) for each row.

Comment: Oh sorry - replace df with x. I'll check when I get to work whether that is what I have done. Maybe this is just a typo! Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I think the problem is the code you left out.

Comment: @Lily check out python syntax, is the `else` an `elif`? Otherwise it make no sense to have a condition. Also what do you return if no condition is matched?